# Javascript:error Unreachable code no-unreachable

Tags: javascript, nodes

I am getting "error  Unreachable code  no-unreachable" during build,I am not able figure out what's wrong init.

```
var flag = false;
function updateTag(pNode, node1){
 if (pNode.code == node1.code){
   flag = true;
   return node1;
 }

 let children = pNode.children;
 if (children && children.length === 0)
   return pNode;

 for (const index in children) {
   const item = children[index];
   children[index] = updateTag(item, node1);
   if(flag)
   break;
 }
 flag = false;
 return pNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the return statement in this piece of code should be wrapped up in **curly braces**

```js
if (children && children.length === 0)
   return pNode;
```

```js
if (children && children.length === 0) {
   return pNode
}
```

It returns the value at the middle of the function so it wont be able to reach the end of it -> therefore '**unreachable code**'